# Popover in Navbar loaded from another file does not work

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, navbar, popover

I am building a site with a navbar that I load from another html file like so:

**Navbar HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Site</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="dashboard">Dashboard</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="popover" href="#" )">Login</a>
    <div id="popover-content" class="d-none">
      <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="loginSubmit">Submit</button>
    </div>    
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="signup.html">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the **jQuery** to pull this into the page:

```
$(function(){
   $("#nav-placeholder").load("navbar.html");
});
```

This works fine and the navbar loads on the page. But within the navbar (if you notice in the code above) there is a popover that I'd like to work when the user clicks on the Login button.

Here is the **popover** code:

```
$('a[rel=popover]').popover();
$("#popover").popover({
    html: true, 
    container: 'body',
    content: function() {
      return $("#popover-content").html();
    }
})
```

This popover works if I have the entire navbar code on the page itself but to keep the code clean I prefer to load the navbar from another file. But when doing that the popover does not work at all. I also get no errors on the console. Nothing happens at all :(

Any suggestions?

Note: To get the navbar to load from another HTML file, I need to run a simpleHTTPServer. Could that be causing an issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the popover in the jQuery load **callback** function.

```
$(function(){
    $("#nav-placeholder").load("navbar.html",function(){
        $('a[rel=popover]').popover();
        $("#popover").popover({
            html: true, 
            container: 'body',
            content: function() {
            return $("#popover-content").html();
        }
        })
    });
});
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/MKC3IwCHuF)

Comment: Awesome! That did it! Thank you very much! Can you let me know why it needed to be in that callback? Is it because the popover needs to be initialized exactly at the Navbar load?

Comment: Yes.. you can't init it until the Navbar has completed loading which is what the callback indicates.

Answer (score 0):

Is Popover Code Before or after the navbar load code?
Popover script should be after navbar load script.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. Yes the popover code is after the navbar load code. All scripts are part of the same js file being called in the html page.

Comment: try putting code in  $(document).ready(function () { //Your Code } or $(function(){ //Your Code })